# Print all possible world configurations

Tags: haskell

Just starting out with Haskell! As an exercise, the current problem I'm trying to implement is as follows:

We have n squares, print all possible world configurations where :

- (1) Each square could have a "P" (pit) or not (2^n possibilities).
- (2) There can be at most one "W" (wumpus) in all n squares (n+1 possibilities).

Representing two squares as two strings, here is an output example for n=2. We have (2^n)·(n+1) = (2^2)·(2+1) = 12 configurations.

```
[[" W"," "],[" "," W"],[" "," "],
 [" W","P"],[" ","PW"],[" ","P"],
 ["PW"," "],["P"," W"],["P"," "],
 ["PW","P"],["P","PW"],["P","P"]]
```

Condition (1) is easily implemented. Looking around, I've found a few ways to express it :

```
p 0 = [[]]
p n = [x:xs | x <- [" ","P"], xs <- p (n-1)]
```

or

```
p n = mapM (\x -> [" ","P"]) [1..n]
```

or

```
p n = replicateM n [" ","P"]
```

I cannot claim to understand the last two yet, but here they are for completeness.

**Question : How can I add condition (2)?** Can it be done with list comprehension?
My not-so-good-looking novice solution involved these functions:

```
insertw :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
insertw n xs 
    | n < 0     = xs
    | n >= lgth = xs
    | otherwise = (take (n) xs) ++ [xs!!n++"W"] ++ (drop (n+1) xs)
    where lgth  = length xs

duplicate :: Int -> [String] -> [[String]]
duplicate i squares 
    | i > lgth   = []
    | otherwise  = (insertw i squares) : duplicate (i+1) squares
    where lgth   = length squares

worlds :: Int -> [[String]]
worlds n = concat . map (duplicate 0) . p $ n
```

Comment: You don't seem to make it clear what a "square" is. Either that or your solution for (1) doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: agree w/ Anon (+1). if i understand the problem correctly then your (1) is not correct. have you run your code for condition (1) alone to see what it produces?

Comment: Yes a square can hold P or can be empty. If we have 2 squares, here are the possible configurations: [[" "," "],[" ","P"],["P"," "],["P","P"]]

Comment: Are the two strings meant to be the two squares?

Comment: @Tim Perry Yes sorry, this must be causing the confusion.

Comment: Ok, I clarified my question as much as I could, added a bit of context. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems obvious to me :).  In list comprehensions, the later lists can depend on the values generated in the earlier ones.  The second function generates your set by calling the first when it adds a wumpus..

```
p 0 = [[]]
p n = [[x,' ']:xs | x <- [' ','P'], xs <- p (n-1)]

pw 0 = [[]]
pw n = [[x,w]:xs | w <- [' ','W'], x <- [' ','P'], xs <- if w == 'W' then p (n-1) else pw (n-1)]
```

it isn't as clean as possible, but I always find list comprehensions bring an elegance to the problem :).  Totally worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Condition 2 isn't an obvious candidate for a list comprehension, but the working code you have already written can be cleaned up.

The iteration from `0` to `lgth` in `duplicate` can be done with a `map` instead of explicit recursion:

```
duplicate squares = map (\i -> insertw i squares) [0 .. length squares]
```

`duplicate` no longer takes an index parameter, and `concat . map` is the same as `concatMap`:

```
worlds = concatMap duplicate . p
```

If you do both a `drop` and a `take`, then `splitAt` is often the better operation.

```
insertw n xs =
    case splitAt n xs of
        (as, []) -> as
        (as, b : bs) -> as ++ ((b ++ "W") : bs)
```

Note that we got rid of the `length xs` and `xs !! n` operations too.

As an exercise, another short `duplicate` function can be written by zipping over the `inits` and `tails` of the `squares` list.

Comment: Very appreciated, thanks a lot for these tips. I will make sure to do this exercise. :)